# How does spin_lock_bh() work?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have a device driver I am working with that has a shared resource between the ISR (more specifically the bottom half of the ISR) and the `read()` call.

The ISR does nothing more than call `schedule_work()` to get the bottom half to do the heavy lifting.  The resource is shared between `read()` (i.e., user context) and the function that implements the bottom half, which is why I am locking with `spin_lock_bh()`.

What I don't understand is the mechanics of the locking.  Say someone currently holds the lock, what happens when the ISR hits `schedule_work()` (i.e., a hardware interrupt fired while we were holding the lock)?  Does the work still get scheduled and then ran at a later time or does it get dropped to the floor?  Stated differently... what is actually "locked" or prevented (i.e., the work queue or the execution of the work)?  Does the work queue get updated?

To contrast my question, I understand that if I were using `spin_lock_irqsave()`, the ISR would be disabled while holding the lock, so I wouldn't get to `schedule_work()` in the first place, but given how the resource is shared, I don't think I need to or want to disable hardware interrupts when holding the lock.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An ISR can't wait for a lock if it might be held by code that does not disable interrupts. That would result in a deadlock.  `spin_lock_irqsave` first disables interrupts, saving the previous state, then takes the lock.  The restore undoes this in reverse order.

A bottom half is still an interrupt.  `spin_lock_bh` does the equivalent by disabling bottom half execution, then taking the lock.  This prevents bottom half execution from stepping on our `read` code.

A lock prevents multiple threads from executing the locked code.  The work queue is protected by only being operated on while holding the lock.

Comment: Sorry, my question was about spin_lock_bh() and how it works when the ISR hits schedule_work() to schedule the bottom half to run.

Comment: Updated to explain bh.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer.  Just for my own clarity... so is only the execution of the bottom half that's prevented, but not the scheduling?  That's how I figured things would work, so that you can then later (after the lock is released) run the bottom half how many times you need to in order to fully service any hardware interrupts that may have showed up while the lock was held.

Comment: The bottom half won't run during the lock but if it was scheduled while the lock was held, I believe it will run as soon as the lock is released. https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/softirq.c#L159

Answer (score 2):

spin_lock_bh disables softirqs (bh is an ancient term that actually refers to softirqs). However, work_queues triggered with schedule_work don't actually run in a softirq but in a dedicated thread, thus process context.

Therefore your driver needs just the simple spin_lock() to protect against concurrent read() calls.

It may need to disable interrupts when accessing resources shared with the "top-half" but that was not the scope of your question.